# Facebook App Links (Deep Linking)

Tags: facebook, applinks

Can't get Facebook app links working FOR THE LIFE of me. I think I got all the tags setup properly:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="1XXX31095767110">
<meta property="og:type" content="music.song">
<meta property="og:title" content="Castle by Halsey on XXX">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://alpha.XXX.com/s/Kzk/?%7B%22scms_mode%22%3Atrue%7D">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://alpha.XXX.com/images/grid/bw/2x/740.png">
<meta property="og:description" content="">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="XXX">
<meta property="al:iphone:url" content="applink://songs/740">
<meta property="al:iphone:app_store_id" content="10XXX22726">
<meta property="al:iphone:app_name" content="XXX">
<meta property="al:web:url" content="https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xxx/id10XXX22726">
```

**applink in the above example is replaced with my app schema and it's included in plist file**

I think I have the app setup on Facebook Properly:

[image]

Things I can think of:

- The app isn't accepted in the app store yet. Though we have it
  running in dev / acceptance, it has a store id, and has the bundles.
- We're not using the SDK and we should be using the SDK. Facebook SDK,
  that is.

Boy - any help would be super appreciated on this one.

Answer (score 3):

It ended up being a meta tag above the og / al meta tags that Facebook didn't like. The Linter didn't pick it up.

If you're having this problem, remove all extraneous tags to start. This should fix your problem. Then add them back in to find the offending tag.

Comment: You should use https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ to rescrape your page

Comment: I use that regularly. Still have intermittent problems.